# Sorting string arrays with fgets

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a program which takes an integer value which then determines the amount of strings that can be inputted, this is looped twice. Once the two sets of strings have been inputted my program should sort them and output them  based on their lengths in descending order. When I output the results I don't get what I should be getting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    int i, num_of_str;
    //int j;
    //int a;
    //int n;
    char input[100];

    scanf("%d", &num_of_str);

    char** strings = malloc(num_of_str * sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_str; i++) {

        fgets(input, 100, stdin);
        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(strings[i], input);
    }

    scanf("%d", &num_of_str);

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_str; i++) {

        fgets(input, 100, stdin);
        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(strings[i], input);
    }

    int a;
    int b;
    char* temp;

    for (a = 0; a < num_of_str; a++) {
        for (b = a + 1; b < num_of_str; b++) {
            if (strlen(strings[a]) < (strlen(strings[b]))) {

                temp = strings[a];
                strings[a] = strings[b];
                strings[b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (a = 0; a < num_of_str; a++) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[a]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: and what is your result? aside: `strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char*));` is missing 1 for null-termination char, and the `sizeof(char*)` error makes up for it but allocating 4 or 8 times the required size... `strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input)+1);` would be correct.

Comment: main problem: you're overwriting your first set of strings with the other one. Why making 2 sets BTW?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre for example if I input 5:
abcdefghijk
abcde
a
abcdefgaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
3:
bb
cccc
hhhhhhhhhhhhhh .     I get the output of: hhhhhhhhhhhhhh
cccc

bb

3.

Comment: @SideWaysCoding don't post complementary information in comments but edit your question.

Comment: @unwind my comment was already deleted before I saw yours.

Comment: Bug: `malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char*));` --> `malloc(strlen(input) + 1);` to allocate room for `\0` and the sizeof is unnecessary and should not be sizeof pointer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie my first comment already mentions that. but the sizeof allocates too much actually (sizeof pointer!)

Comment: Are you sure you need to use bubble sort for this? Why not just use `qsort()`?

Comment: @RoadRunner I'm not too familiar with qsort so that's why I tired bubblesort. The thing is though I'm not sure if qsort would fix my problem?

Comment: Sorting is the least of your worries in this code, and frankly, even with memory management fixed, there is still a *major* problem. Your line retrieval management is wrong. Think about this:  (a) you never check the success or failure of *any* of your IO operations. (b) you read a count, but the rest of the line from whence it was pulled is still sitting in the input stream, so your very first line pull in the loop will just be the rest of that line. (c) That completely throws off all the remaining operations, not that you notice because as I said with (a), you never check your IO ops.

Comment: @WhozCraig I had printf's before in my code, right after the first and second for loop to see if the the input was being recorded and it seems like it was.

Comment: @SideWaysCoding It just doesn't make sense why you would add strings from set 1, then replace them straight after with strings from set 2. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: I'm just telling you: What you have posted now, given the input file format, which I can only assume is mashed in the question [and actually looks like this](http://pastebin.com/B2vTeBSV), *will not work*, even with the memory allocation fixes in place. The `scanf` does not absorb the trailing newline following the count, so the ensuing first `fgets` in your loop *will*. From then, all lines are off by one, and the position you expect to find the second count *will not line up*. Instead, the input string is sitting on what should have been the *last* string from the first section.

Comment: Also your second `scanf("%d", &numstr)` will not update whats being allocated in `**strings`. If you get a bigger `numstr` value on the second `scanf()`, you will be accessing past the limit of `strings`.

Comment: So is most of this code useless? Should I just start again? I thought my first part of the code was somewhat ok.

Comment: @RoadRunner Well should I use an integer to store the input instead of trying to use `fgets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the issues in your code:

- Return pointer `malloc()` is not being checked. It needs to be checked as the `void*` pointer from it can return `NULL` if unsuccessful. You can check `malloc()` like this:

  ```
  ptr = malloc(......);
  if (ptr == NULL) {
      /* handle error */
  }
  ```
- Return value of `scanf()` is not being checked. This needs to check if 1 integer value for `numstr` was found. You can verify this like:

  ```
  if (scanf("%d", &numstr) != 1) {
      /* handle error */
  }
  ```
- `strings[i]` is not being allocated properly. Since this is a `char*` pointer, you need to allocate a number of `char` bytes, not `char*` pointers. You also need to add `+1` to your allocation, to ensure their is enough space for the null-terminator `\0`.  So instead of:

  ```
  strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char*));
  ```

  You can do:

  ```
  strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
  ```

  **Note:** `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so no need to include it here.
- Your code does not update `**strings` on the second `numstr`. This will lead to issues if `numstr` ends up being a bigger, in which you will be accessing beyond the limit of `**strings`. You may need to use [`realloc(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) here, to resize your block of memory. A way you can do this is to keep track of the first `numstr`, then check it against the second `numstr`, and if they are different, resize `strings`.
  Here is an example:

  ```
  prev_numstr = numstr;

  printf("Enter number of strings for set 2:\n");
  if (scanf("%zu ", &numstr) != 1) {
      /* handle exit */
  }

  if (numstr != prev_numstr) {
      void *temp = realloc(strings, numstr * sizeof(*strings));
      if (temp == NULL) {
          /* handle exit */
      }
      strings = temp;
  }
  ```
- Since `scanf()` leaves a `\n` character in the input buffer, you need to get rid of this before your call to `fgets()`. You can simply add a space by doing `scanf("%d ", &num_of_str)`, which will consume any white space still left in the buffer.
- `fgets()` must be checked, as it can return a `NULL` pointer on failure to read a line. It also appends a `\n` character at the end of the buffer, so you might need to remove this newline sometime.
- Any heap allocation made with `malloc()` and `realloc()` must be de-allocated with [`free(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) at the end.
- Since `void *malloc(size_t size)` expects `size_t`, it is better to use `size_t` variables here instead.

Since your code doesn't have issues with sorting, here is some example code that uses these points:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 100

int main(void) {
    char input[LINESIZE];
    size_t numstr, prev_numstr, slen;
    void *temp = NULL;

    printf("Enter number of strings for set 1:\n");
    if (scanf("%zu ", &numstr) != 1 || numstr < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid value\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char **strings = malloc(numstr * sizeof(*strings));
    if (strings == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate %zu strings\n", numstr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Set 1 */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numstr; i++) {
        if (fgets(input, LINESIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
            slen = strlen(input);

            /* removes newline */
            if (slen > 0 && input[slen-1] == '\n') {
                input[slen-1] = '\0';
            }

            strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
            if (strings[i] == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate %zu bytes for string\n", strlen(input)+1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            strcpy(strings[i], input);
        }       
    }

    /* keeps track of previous number of strings */
    prev_numstr = numstr;

    printf("Enter number of strings for set 2:\n");
    if (scanf("%zu ", &numstr) != 1 || numstr < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid value\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* only enters if size is different */
    if (numstr != prev_numstr) {
        temp = realloc(strings, numstr * sizeof(*strings));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot reallocate %zu spaces\n", numstr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* perhaps temp could could freed here */
        strings = temp;
    } 

    /* Set 2 */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numstr; i++) {
        if (fgets(input, LINESIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
            slen = strlen(input);
            if (slen > 0 && input[slen-1] == '\n') {
                input[slen-1] = '\0';
            }

            strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
            if (strings[i] == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate %zu bytes for string\n", strlen(input)+1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            strcpy(strings[i], input);
        }       
    }

    /* printing and freeing strings */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numstr; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
        free(strings[i]);
        strings[i] = NULL;
    }

    /* freeing double pointer 'strings' itself */
    free(strings);
    strings = NULL;

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Note:** I assumed you still wanted to take in 2 sets, and overwrite the first one with the second one, which does seem odd, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are taking 2 sets,one thing I wanted to mention you are using
scanf for getting no of strings & fgets for string. So, you may loose 1st entry
because of this.